# Artefacts during HDV capture

Tags: hdvideo, video-capture

When I try to capture HDV video stream from a Canon HV20 camera to a Dell Studio 1558 (Intel i7 720qm) laptop running Win 7 Home Premium x64, the image appears with a very annoying noise - it contains block artefacts. Something is wrong with the Fire Wire controller (Ricoh 1304 OHCI host controller, build-in). Tried changing the driver to legacy one to no avail.

This does not happen with DV stream.

I'm using a Belkin cable.

The capture works OK on another machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a poor 64-bit compatibility of the drivers and/or capturing software. But since I experience the same issue with many video capture packages I would bet it's the driver's fault.